# Unit test Angular UI Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, unit-testing

I am new to angular and jasmine unit testing and trying to test modal open close for the controller below, I have tried writing a unit test to inject the modal but now I dont know how to test the methods inside. Need some guidance

Controller:

```
app.controller('feedDetailsController', function($scope, $modal, $log, feedDealService) {
    var modalController = function($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    };

    /**
     * Displays feed details modal
     *
     * @param object currentPub
     */
    $scope.showForm = function(currentPub) {

        $scope.currentPub = currentPub;

        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/feedDetails/_feedDetails.html',
            controller: modalController,
            scope: $scope,
            windowClass: 'tm-modal feed-details-dialog',
            resolve: {
                feedDealModal: function() {
                    $scope.modal = {
                        title: 'Feed Details',
                        headers: {
                            col1: 'Col1',
                            col2: 'Col2',
                            col3: 'Col3',
                            col4: 'Col4'
                        },
                        feedDeals: feedDealService.getDeals(currentPub),
                        hasCancel: true,
                        hasSubmit: false
                    };
                    $scope.setDealAccess = function(dealId) {
                        feedDealService.updateDeal($scope.publishers, currentPub, dealId);
                    };
                    return $scope.feedDealModal;
                }
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Test:

```
describe('feedDetailsController', function() {

    beforeEach(module('premiumInventoryApp'));

    var MainCtrl, scope;

    var fakeModal = {
        result: {
            then: function(confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
                //Store the callbacks for later when the user clicks on the OK or Cancel button of the dialog
                this.confirmCallBack = confirmCallback;
                this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
            }
        },
        close: function( item ) {
            //The user clicked OK on the modal dialog, call the stored confirm callback with the selected item
            this.result.confirmCallBack( item );
        },
        dismiss: function( type ) {
            //The user clicked cancel on the modal dialog, call the stored cancel callback
            this.result.cancelCallback( type );
        }
    };

    beforeEach(inject(function($modal) {
        spyOn($modal, 'open').and.returnValue(fakeModal);
    }));

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$modal_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        MainCtrl = $controller('feedDetailsController', {
            $scope: scope,
            $modal: _$modal_
        });
    }));

    it('should open a modal', function () 

        // Mock out the modal closing, resolving with a selected item, say 1
        scope.showForm(); // Open the modal
        scope.modalInstance.close();
        expect(scope.showForm).toEqual(fakeModal);
    });
});
```